# Postgres JDBC thread stuck on java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0 even though timeout was defined

Tags: java, multithreading, postgresql, wildfly, eclipselink

We are using a Java app on a Wildfly 16 connected with a Postgres 9.4 database using EclipseLink. The Application Server is configured to use connection pooling. The app is indexing items to a Solr instance over night and from time to time we had problems with blocking threads. It seems that a database query isn't returning after all. We set a timeout for queries in our 
persistence unit, which doesn't seem to work. We added following entry in our persistence.xml:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.query.timeout" value="30000"/>
```

The system is using a Java 11 jre. We are using the docker wildfly image (https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/wildfly/dockerfile) as a base, but have seen this problems with other Application Servers and Java versions as well.

The thread dump shows some details. The process is running multiple hours. We were expecting that a exception would be thrown after 30s. What are we missing?

```
"Indexer thread" #181 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=3845600.45ms elapsed=124856.57s tid=0x000000000a51b800 nid=0x12d runnable  [0x00007fb51dcb9000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(java.base@11.0.4/Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(java.base@11.0.4/SocketInputStream.java:115)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(java.base@11.0.4/SocketInputStream.java:168)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(java.base@11.0.4/SocketInputStream.java:140)
        at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:146)
        at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:115)
        at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:71)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.ReceiveChar(PGStream.java:283)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1719)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:173)
        - locked  (a org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:622)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:472)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeUpdate(PgStatement.java:429)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@11.0.4/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@11.0.4/Method.java:566)
        at org.postgresql.ds.PGPooledConnection$StatementHandler.invoke(PGPooledConnection.java:466)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy69.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:537)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:898)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:970)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:640)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:567)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2096)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:275)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:261)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.updateObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:832)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.updateObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:437)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.updateObjectForWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:1093)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.UpdateObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(UpdateObjectQuery.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:316)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:914)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:813)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:87)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2981)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1895)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1877)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1827)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitChangedObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:275)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:133)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:4387)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1493)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1583)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitRootUnitOfWork(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:280)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1220)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:136)
        at com.freiheit.vrms.persistence.SystemObjectPersistenceService.createOrUpdateNextIndexerRun(SystemObjectPersistenceService.java:2134)
        at com.freiheit.vrms.service.search.SearchService.attributeIndexFields(SearchService.java:322)
        at com.freiheit.vrms.service.search.SearchService.indexObjectInternal(SearchService.java:848)
        at com.freiheit.vrms.service.search.SearchService.indexObjectInForeground(SearchService.java:752)
        - locked  (a java.lang.Object)
        at com.freiheit.vrms.service.search.SearchService.indexObjectInForeground(SearchService.java:746)
        at com.freiheit.vrms.service.search.IndexJob$JobType$2.execute(IndexJob.java:60)
        at com.freiheit.vrms.service.search.IndexJob.execute(IndexJob.java:104)
        at com.freiheit.vrms.service.search.IndexQueue.handleMessage(IndexQueue.java:243)
        at com.freiheit.vrms.service.search.IndexQueue.run(IndexQueue.java:155)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.4/Thread.java:834)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        -  (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$FairSync)
```

**EDIT:**
I would like to add some additional code, which causes the thread to freeze.

```
final EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
transaction.begin();
updateNextIndexerRun( em, id, nextIndexerRun );
transaction.commit();
```

As shown above the thread stucked at the line `transaction.commit()`. This snippet is called thousands of times a day and isn't making any trouble most of the time. the table in which the data will be persisted has ~20000 entries at a time. The method `updateNextIndexerRun` is defined this way:

```
private void updateNextIndexerRun( final EntityManager em, final Long id, @Nullable final Calendar newNextIndexerRun ) {

    final NextIndexerRunDBBean oldNextIndexerRun = getNextIndexerRun( em, id );

    if ( newNextIndexerRun == null && oldNextIndexerRun != null ) {
        em.remove( oldNextIndexerRun );
    } else if ( newNextIndexerRun != null ) {
        if ( oldNextIndexerRun == null ) {
            em.persist( new NextIndexerRunDBBean( id, newNextIndexerRun ) );
        } else {
            em.merge( new NextIndexerRunDBBean( id, newNextIndexerRun ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The query itself is run under 30 seconds, so the timeout isn't being applied. Now from [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/query-timeout-jpa-hibernate/) we see

> the JPQL query above will time out after 50 milliseconds **unless the
>   result set is being fetched prior to the timeout threshold.**

You're already reading the resultset, but it's either too large or there's a problem reading it fast enough.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've added extra code to show that we don't read data, instead we persist data on a quite small table. Do you have any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: @a.ha I assume this isn't relevant either? https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=456067

Comment: In any case, the mystery lies most likely in the database (and perhaps EclipseLink). You might want to pop over to [dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com) for help regarding those (just don't tell a_horse_with_no_name that you're using an ORM). You might also want to log some session details when doing a commit, see how many objects are waiting for persistence. Haven't used EclipseLink, but I assume you can get some statistics from it somehow..